# TV Tuner Recording Problems

Tags: video, recording, tuner-card

I use a tv tuner to record a few shows, but I am unsatisfied with a few things:

1. The sound\audio seems to be very low
   when played back
2. The output file is .ts and the files
   are rather large - most video files
   that I've seen are either avi or mkv

I'm pretty new to this so it got me wondering...is there some sort of software that I should be using to fix these issues? Or is this a hardware issue?

[This is the tv tuner](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815116028) I'm using with the default software.

EDIT: It seems the sound problem may be related to the line feed - I forgot to mention that the line is not coming directly in from cable, but rather from a tuner box. I don't know if someone can confirm this or not.

TIA

Comment: Try recording the audio from the tuner box on another device and compare.

Comment: try connecting the cable line directly to the tuner

Comment: @Xantec: The line from the tuner is split going to the tuner card and a tv. However, the tuner does allow the volume to be adjusted. I think I'll try a simple test with the tuner volume all the way up and see if that fixes the volume.

Comment: Any time you split a signal like that, you risk degradation, and audio is fairly fickle to that sort of signal path modification. You might want to invest in higher quality cables or just not split the signal when you record.

Comment: @MaQleod - I'll have to work on that then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm that this will work with all setups, but for me personally, since my cable line was coming from a tuner with an audio remote my sound problems were solved by simply turning up the volume on the tuner.

As far as .TS files go - I think that is the standard. There are plenty of apps out there that convert these files over to other formats.